# SonarLint ignores quality profile from server

Tags: sonarlint, sonarlint-eclipse

Using SonarLint 2.0.0 with Eclipse Mars.2 and SonarQube Server 5.3, I have a Maven multi-module project with each module connected to the corresponding project component on the SonarQube Server. The server uses a custom quality profile.

I've manually updated the issues from the server, but the issues I see in Eclipse are not in sync with the issues on SonarQube.

Eclipse displays some issues for rules that are deactivated in my profile, but misses lots of issues from other rules of my profile.

What's wrong here?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean with "update the issues from the server". Did you try to update the data from the SonarQube server in Eclipse?

Comment: Yes, exactly, from the Sonar Server view.

Comment: I have the same issue, have you solved it?

Answer (score 3):

Can confirm this issue with SonarLint 2.0.0 on Eclipse Mars.2 and SonarQube Server 5.4.

The SonarQube Server has a custom Quality Profile which is configured as default for all projects, yet it seems to be not taken into account by SonarLint.

Answer (score 1):

I confirm the issue on SonarLint for Visual Studio and SonarQube Server 5.4.
SonarLint uses generic default rules, instead of custom Quality Profile defined on server.